# How to turn off errors log page on server version in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I just moved my new project to the server, and I don't want the people to see the errors page and instead redirect them somewhere else. But I need to keep this page in my development environment. How can I turn off error logging page in Laravel, and redirect users to some kind of "Oops..." page?
The page I am toking about is on the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turn off debug mode in your `.env` file.

While you're at it, don't forget to set the environment to production as well. This will add a warning when executing certain actions like running migrations.

```
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel error details is "true" by default.

you can turn off this simply setting on `debug` option on your `app/config/app.php` or you can set debug from `.env`

Answer (score 0):

In your `.env` file, set APP_DEBUG=false. With that, when an error occurs, it shows the user a white background 500 error page, and only logs the error in your log files.

You can also customise the error page, by first creating an errors folder in /resources/views. Then create 404.php for 404 errors, 500.php for error 500.